# symfony 2 - object created twice

Tags: php, database, symfony, object, doctrine

In my current symfony project i work with doctrine.

in one of my controllers i am creating an object and saving it to the db:

```
$article = new Article();
$article->setName('article');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();

$data = $this->prepareIndexAction();

$html = $this->container->get('templating')->render(
    'index.html.twig',
    ['data' => $data]
);

return new Response($html);
```

This object is saved two times to the database.

Anybody knows how to deal with this?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: try removing `$article->setName('article');`

Comment: what hapens in the  prepareIndexAction ? and also is there a form that user submits ?

Comment: Check your logs, chances are the controller action is actually invoked twice

Comment: show your article class. Check constructor

Comment: is your controller called twice? check it by placing a simple echo into the controller.

Comment: To sum up - we have to know more about your folder structure. At least provide your controller class with all concerned actions (prepareIndexAction, name and route of the action you use to persist). Then, describe how you submit the form. There is a high chance that 1. you submit the form twice or 2. you call submit action from inside of your controller flow (eg from `prepareIndexAction`).

Comment: Simple solution: xDebug!! place a breakpoint at line1 of this action. See if it's being called more than once. Follow the whole execution process, you'll learn alot.